# Join a user field to a profile2 field in a view

Tags: views, users

What I am trying to do is to join fields that are a user type (e.g. image, and username) to Profile2 fields.
In the example I want to join:

- teacher name (teacher profile2)
- teacher date (teacher profile2)
- username (drupal registration)

What I mean by Drupal registration is the fields used to register an account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to the display profile fields using the Views module, then follow these steps:

1. Add "User:profile" under "RELATIONSHIPS".
2. Select "Profile types" in which type you have your fields to be display (teacher name, teacher date), as you may have more than one profile types.
3. You can add the selected profile fields under "Fields".